# Openwhisk - passing environment variables to action

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, openwhisk

Im using NodeJS action in openwhisk.
Is there any way to pass environment variables into whisk so I can read them in my NodeJS action using process.env ?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible but you need to use a [custom Docker runtime](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions-docker.md). The default built-in Node.js runtime does not support this. Apache OpenWhisk uses [default action parameters](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/parameters.md#setting-default-parameters-on-an-action), rather than environment parameters, to pass things like credentials and other application configuration to action code.

If you extend the existing Node.js Docker runtime for Apache OpenWhisk, you can set environment parameters in the build file for the image. This can then be used as the `--docker` parameter value when creating the action.